# How to test if a passive mob is a baby with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to find out, in a command block, if a targeted mob (cow, sheep, chicken, etc.) is a baby or an adult. I know that's determined by the Age data tag: if Age<0, it's a baby, otherwise it's an adult. The problem is, as far as I know, there's no way to check if a data tag is <0, you can only test for exact values.

I'm able to detect the moment when a baby grows up, since the Age passes through -1 in that case (not checking 0 to avoid detection of newly spawned adults). But how can I tell whether a passive mob is a baby or an adult before that moment triggers (especially since adults won't have that moment at all)?

Comment: I don't say this often, but I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want to do.  I thought it would be possible to do this using the scoreboar (probably with a little help from the `stats` command), but I'm not seeing anything useful that also doesn't include a massive number of command blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a mob is a baby, InLove will be constantly set to 0. If it's an adult, it'll slowly decrease to 0. So, you should be able to run these, in this exact order:

```
scoreboard players set @e[score_checkAge_min=1] isBaby 0
scoreboard players set @e[score_checkAge_min=1] isBaby 1 {InLove:0}
entitydata @e[score_checkAge_min=1] {InLove:0}
scoreboard players set @e checkAge 0
scoreboard players set @e checkAge 1 {InLove:0}
entitydata @e[score_checkAge_min=1] {InLove:30000}
```

`InLove` only exists on animals, so you don't have to worry about it setting the score for players or other non-animals.

This method should work for 1.8 and horses.

#### Breakdown

```
scoreboard players set @e checkAge 0
scoreboard players set @e checkAge 1 {InLove:0}
```

This sets a `checkAge` dummy score to 1 for all not-currently-breeding passive mobs, adult and child.

```
 entitydata @e[score_checkAge_min=1] {InLove:30000}
```

Changes the `InLove` tag of previously selected entities to 30000.

Then, in the next tick:

```
scoreboard players set @e[score_checkAge_min=1] isBaby 0
scoreboard players set @e[score_checkAge_min=1] isBaby 1 {InLove:0}
```

Sets isBaby to 1 if InLove has instantly returned to 0, or 0 otherwise.

```
entitydata @e[score_checkAge_min=1] {InLove:0}
```

Sets InLove back to 0 for all checked entities.

---

You should be able to select adults like this:

```
@e[score_isBaby=0]
```

Or babies like this:

```
@e[score_isBaby_min=1]
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to @MBraedly's, simply because it'll immediately detect all applicable mobs regardless of their initial InLove value. Thanks!

Comment: Wait...in trying to implement this, it doesn't work as well as I'd hoped. It seems to also detect animals that have bred in the last tick. I don't really understand why; the logic behind your idea seems solid. I manually set InLove to 30000 and checked the entitydata, and it properly stays high and decrements by 1 each tick; yet somehow, when the animals breed, they get marked as babies anyway. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Hmm, I thought it would have at worst just waited a second before tagging mobs that had just bred; I'll do some more testing with mobs that have just bred and try to figure that out.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk My method will immediately detect almost all applicable mobs, because the InLove timer is only 10 seconds and the breeding timer is 5 minutes.  All you need to do to make this work 100% of the time is idle for 5 minutes before activating the command blocks.

Comment: @MBraedley Right, but for my particular use case, it needs to be running on a 20 tps clock, so I can't wait 5 minutes before running it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @colorfusion Thanks. In my testing, I couldn't figure out what was going on. It was as though the just-mated animals were getting InLove immediately reset to 0, since the next tick it was never passing through 2999 (from 3000), which is weird because as I said, when I turn off the command blocks and manually set their InLove to 3000, it starts decrementing properly.

If you figure it out, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Why not?  Once it's running, it's running.  I specifically said I'm using 1.9, and hence a repeating command block followed by chain command blocks.  That runs at 20Hz.  And if it's a brand new world, there won't be a problem: new friendly mobs spawn with an age of 0, unless they're a baby.  It seems like you're dismissing my answer because you don't understand it, and not on its merits, in which case you should be asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

[MBraedley's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/240706) doesn't work at all in its current state. GIF demonstration:

[image: demonstration]

[colorfusion's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/240704) somewhat works, but messes up with breeding as you appear to have noticed.

The following method is a bit of a hybrid between the two that I believe works 100% of the time.

---

Add these objectives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add CheckAge dummy
/scoreboard objectives add GrowthLevel dummy
```

On your clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @e CheckAge 1 {InLove:0}
/scoreboard players add @e[score_CheckAge_min=1] GrowthLevel 0
/scoreboard players set @e[score_CheckAge_min=1] GrowthLevel 1 {Age:0}
```

Then use `@e[score_GrowthLevel_min=1]` to select adults, or `@e[score_GrowthLevel=0]` for babies.

Comment: I can't test this until later tonight, but how does that handle adults that spawned before the clock started (i.e. were already in the world before I turned the system on)? Their age would be >0 at all times, so wouldn't they be mistagged as babies?

Comment: I guess @colorfusion was at least partially right in one of his comments on my answer.  I've fixed the problem.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Should work fine. Adults usually have age 0, not >0.

Comment: @MBraedley Their comment wasn't "at least partially right", it was fully right. Not being able to specify multiple selector arguments is a fairly basic thing, and I'm not sure how you tested your method to work correctly.

Comment: I swear I ran a command that worked as expected using two two tags in the selector.  Now perhaps it worked because of an edge case in my test, or I just didn't notice that it wasn't working right, but what's important is I've fixed the issue, and have fully tested it.

Comment: @MBraedley Your second solution will mostly work now (pretty much the same as mine, but with tags instead of scoreboards, and without the first command which was there to stop it targeting other things with Age like summoned AreaEffectClouds).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose those have Age too.  They don't have InLove, so if that's added to the first command, it'll exclude them.

Comment: @MBraedley OP did ask how to find "if a targeted mob [..] is a baby or an adult" (though not in the title), so you may want to add to your answer that `tag=Adult` in your version will select more than just adult animals.

Comment: @SirBenet According to the Wiki, an adult that has just bred will have age>0, specifying the number of ticks until it can breed again. So perhaps I was wrong in saying they "always have" the Age>0, but would that not mean your version would also mistag recently-bred adults, similar to the issue with colorfusion's idea? (Again, can't test it until later, I'm just analyzing it at the moment.)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk This never sets the score of animals that have already been identified as adults back to 0. If you're breeding animals right as you build the clock, then it'll just take a few moments to set the breeding animals' score, but that's a one time thing and will only occur when you first build the clock. After it's built, it'll tag any mobs immediately.

Answer (score 1):

So my comment above was wrong, this is doable, albeit with a caveat.  The important thing to realize is [what the Age tag actually represents](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Mobs):

> Age: Represents the age of the mob in ticks; when negative, the mob is a baby. When 0 or above, the mob is an adult. When above 0, represents the number of ticks before this mob can breed again.

So, *all* friendly mobs will have an Age of 0 unless they're either a baby or were recently bred.  This means we can easily tag them with a scoreboard value.  Now we won't get newly minted parents, but if we use version 1.9 (or, at this point, the snapshots for 1.9), we don't have to worry about that, since we're going to tag all adults ready to breed.  Even after you breed them, they'll still keep their tag; adults can't turn back into babies, so there's no reason to remove the tag.

So, it's fairly simple: just tag all entities with an Age of 0 as an adult.

```
/scoreboard players tag @e add Adult {Age:0}
```

Run that in a repeating command block, and all friendly mobs that are adults will have the tag unless they recently bred.

Now, to get all the babies is a little more complicated.  The naive approach below isn't very desirable:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e remove Baby
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=!Adult] add Baby
```

That will tag every single entity, including players, as a baby if they aren't already tagged as an adult.  Not great.  What we need to do is be able to distinguish friendly mobs from every other entity.  Luckily, there is a way to do this:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e add FriendlyMob {InLove:0}
```

So, your commands, in order, should be:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e add FriendlyMob {InLove:0}
/scoreboard players tag @e add Adult {Age:0}
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=!Adult] add Baby
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=!FriendlyMob] remove Baby
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=Adult] remove Baby
```

The only friendly mobs this won't work correctly with are mobs that are about to breed, or have just bred, and still, once those two timers reach 0 again, they'll be properly tagged.  This won't take long either.  The timer for InLove is only 10 seconds, and the timer for Age is 5 minutes.  In most cases, you won't have to wait at all.

Hopefully it's self evident, but in order to select the adults, just use `@e[tag=Adult]`, and similarly for the babies, use `@e[tag=Baby]`.

---

SirBenet's answer made me realize I could simplify things a little (well, a lot): I don't need to actually tag friendly mobs, I can just do a data tag check instead:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e add Adult {Age:0}
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=!Adult] add Baby {InLove:0}
/scoreboard players tag @e[tag=Adult] remove Baby
```

As before, if the Age or InLove timers are counting down, it won't tag the mob properly, but unless you're willing to go mess with those, there isn't really a way around it.

Comment: Why they couldn't just use `IsBaby` like for Zombies is beyond me.

Comment: "`@e[tag=!Adult,tag=FriendlyMob]`" - Have you tested this? Didn't think you could select multiple tags. Easy enough to change it to scoreboard though, and should be more compact than my suggested method.

Comment: It's basically the same as scores.  Pretty sure you can select multiple scores.

Comment: And just to be sure, I just tested it.  Works as expected.

Comment: I guess I wasn't doing a valid test last night.  A little rearrangement and an additional command sorted everything out.